# PHP Dom Document Don't fix markup

Tags: php, domdocument

How do I stop DOMDocument from having a mind of its own?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$validHtml = '<body><a href="{{ var name=test method=toString }}">Test</a></body>';
$dom->loadHTML($validHtml);
```

After loading, the anchor attribute is encoded. I want it not to do this.

```
$body = $dom->saveHTML();
var_dump($body);
//<body><a href="%7B%7B%20var%20name=test%20method=toString%20%7D%7D">Test</a></body>
```

I realize this has been covered before, but every where I look, it's more useless Ninja code. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this can be changed, but if it can, it will probably be through changing the DTD.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed my own problem. Basically, I decided to strip out all the tags in the markup and put in place holders that I can use later use to put back in:

```
    $validHtml = '<body><a href="{{ var name=test method=toString }}">Test</a></body>';

    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('/{{[^}]+}}/',$validHtml, $matches);

    $matches = $matches[0];
    if (count($matches)>0){
       foreach ($matches as $i=>$match){
           $validHtml = str_replace($match, "<!--INDEX-$i-->", $validHtml);
       }
    }
    $dom = new DOMDocument();  
    $dom->loadHTML($validHtml);

... //do processing on the loaded dom
```

Later on after manipulating the dom, I put back all the matches:

```
    $validHtml = $dom->saveHTML();

    if (count($matches)>0){
        foreach ($matches as $i=>$match){
            $validHtml = str_replace(array("<!--INDEX-$i-->", "&lt;!--INDEX-$i--&gt;"), $match, $validHtml);
        }
    }
```